# Is there a way to construct an object automatically from an NSDictionary?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm building an iPhone app that communicates with an external server via JSON. The JSON library I'm using parses the response string from the server into a dictionary. Currently I've got a method that I've written that just uses hardcoded strings as keys for the dictionary in a constructor I've written called `initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dic` (e.g. `self.name = [dic valueForKey:@"name"];`. Is there some smart idiomatic Objective-C way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just call [someObject setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:dictFromJSON] to set an object's properties from a dictionary.